# How can I track the effect of high cardinality on a Prometheus server?

Tags: prometheus, metrics

[This link](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/instrumentation/#do-not-overuse-labels) gives interesting insights:

- Cardinality below 10 is optimal, while exceeding 100 is a warning sign.
- Prometheus can handle up to 100K metrics, but 100KK is unsustainable.

Considering [Prometheus’s architecture](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus#architecture-overview):

- Higher cardinality leads to increased server resource utilization and slower PromQL query responses.
- It also impacts the efficiency of time-series data ingestion.

I would like to know how to monitor:

- the number of metrics stored in Prometheus storage.
- Prometheus server resource usage.
- PromQL query response times.
- performance of time-series data ingestion.

Comment: This is a question about self-monitoring of monitoring tool. Nothing of this seems to be development related. Also, most of your points require quite a bit of clarification before they can be answered precisely (but you can check metrics that prometheus itself exposes, to find most of what you probably needed).